# Как правильно записать условие для цикла?

Tags: java, классы, while

Есть главный цикл. Он должен работать пока `String v` не равно  "exit". Переменная v находится в классе Peremens. Мой вариант кода вызывает ошибку:

```
Peremens per = new Peremens(); // создаём объект класса
while (!per.v.equals("exit")){
    ...
}
```

А Когда я объявил переменную в классе Main...

```
while (!v.equals("exit")){
    ...
}
```

...То ошибки нет. Хотелось бы знать, как избежать ошибки если я хочу чтобы v была в классе Peremens.

Comment: и почему вы поменяли вопрос на другой, когда ответ был дан?

Comment: Ответ был дан, и он был правильный. Но проблема, из-за которой я обратился за помощью, решена не была.  Спасибо.

Comment: С тем условием что было - он был верным. А то, что это был другой класс с переменной - упомянуто не было. И это была твоя ошибка... И это конечно должно быть немного другим ответом... лично я хочу сейчас просто откатить вопрос к его изначальному варианту....

Comment: В следующий раз стоит писать более развернуто вопросы - где что у тебя находится, приводить больше кода и т.д., а не скрывать детали)) Ибо от этого зависит и сам ответ

Comment: Учту, я просто думал что нет разницы где была переменная, и задал вопрос по-короче))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Переменная v находится в классе Peremens

Какая область видимости у это переменной? Из соображений инкапсуляции неправильно напрямую обращаться к `v`:

```
while (!per.v.equals("exit")){
    ...
}
```

Необходимо создать геттер для этого поля и обращаться через него:

```
while (!per.getV().equals("exit")){
    ...
}
```

Вы уверены, что v всегда будет инициализировано и не равно null? Если это не так, то вы рискуете получить `NullPointerException` при попытке вызова метода equals. Необходимо проверять предвариательно на неравенство null или делать так:

```
while (!"exit".equals(per.getV())){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Наверное

```
while (!v.equals("exit")){
```

`!` - отрицание, наподобие `!=` (неравно)